# Android Unable to resolve host

Tags: android, client

I am new to Android, so this question might have a simple answer(I might have missed something). I am trying to make a REST client with the help of the Resting framework from Google(because Jersey didn't seem to work). When I try to run the client, I get this warning:

`W/System.err(728): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "my.ip:8080": No address associated with hostname`

and then I get a few Exceptions, but I guess that this is the root cause.

I have the internet permission:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.maze.client"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".RestingClientActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

If you need any additional information, please let me know.

- In the warning I replaced my IP with "mi.ip"(it is intentionally done, but in the original it is all right).

Comment: have you tried restarting emulator, I got this exception many times, but after restarting emulator, problem get solved. try if you haven't tried

Comment: @NixitPatel I have restarted the emulator several times and then I have restarted eclipse, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: Try running it on a device; sometimes the emultator screws up. I know I have a similar issue with streaming .mjpeg files on the emulator; crashes on the emulator but runs perfect on my device.

Comment: @TJBiddle I do not own a smartphone. I know it is weird that I try to make applications for something I don't have. :D

Comment: are you trying to use this on local machine or the pc connected to the lan

Comment: @NixitPatel I do not understand exactly what you are asking. The thing is, I am having eclipse installed on my computer and I am trying to run the program on the Android Virtual device. My computer is connected to the internet through LAN.

Comment: what i am saying the host you are try to access is in internal lan or localhost or some web url

Comment: @NixitPatel The host is localhost, but I know that I shouldn't write `http://localhost:8080/...`, so I wrote `http://111.11.111.11:8080` where `111.11.111.11` is my ip(example). It is the right one, since I can access the server from the emulator's browser.

Comment: @Dragos if your server is linux so pls check your host file that has at least a hostname which shoud mapped with your ip like example.com 192.1.1.1

Comment: The rest of the comments are on the right track: Name resolution is the first thing that happens when you attempt a network connection.  This message, likely, has nothing to do with DNS.  It probably just means you have no network connection at all.  Try running the browser on the AVD.  Does it work?  Next try using the browser on the AVD to connect to your target machine.  That should help you to identify exactly where the problem lies...

Answer (score 1):

If you post the piece of code where you do the connection to the server, it will be easier to help you.
But, probably your problem is on creating the URI to be called. Example:

```
URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "your-ip", 8080, "/path/to/webservice", 
        URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8"), null);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
response = client.execute(get);
```

So, if you call the execute method with an invalid or a wrong URI, you could have a problem.

Or, sometimes, when you keep your AVD opened and change the network you are using, for example, go out of the office and start using you home wifi, you should get a problem like this you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same issue as the OP, I know this is an old question but will post my findings anyway.

The problem is that the Resting framework methods like get() passes the url through its connection helpers, and expects you to provide the port as the second parameter.

So taking OP's example, instead of:

```
Resting.get('my.ip:8080');
```

your call should be:

```
Resting.get('my.ip', 8080)
```

Hope that helps someone :)